# DrawLine method doesn't work when using inside a loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a program that is able to read a dxf file and plot it's contents but when I try to draw the figures in the window's paint event, nothing is drawn unless I use `this.Invalidate();` and this doesn't completely work because the objects appear to blink on the screen. The coordinates to draw the lines are stored in a list declared in the window class.

```
private void InitialWindow_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    if (entities.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < entities.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < entities[i].path.Count - 1; k++)
            {
                g.DrawLine(blackPen, D2F(entities[i].path[k]), D2F(entities[i].path[k + 1]));
            }
            g.DrawLine(blackPen, D2F(entities[i].path[0]), D2F(entities[i].path.Last()));
        }
    }
}
```

2DF is a function that converts a point-like type of data to PointF so it can be used in DrawLine. If I try to draw outside the for loops the lines are displayed correctly on the screen. Thanks in advance for any help with it.

Comment: Is the `entities` collection already filled when you first show this Control / Form? -- *nothing is drawn unless I use `this.Invalidate()`*: unless you call `Invalidate()` where / when? -- You should probably describe what your collection contains.

Comment: You can invalidate a region, not just a whole window. Back when I did graphical program (Win32 on 1990s class machines), we'd build regions around what we were going to draw, and just invalidate those regions. If the user moved something, we'd invalidate where it used to be, them invalidate where it got moved to. WinForms also has a double buffering mechanism (which will reduce flicker).

Comment: You do not need the `if()` statement as the loop isn't going to happen when `Count == 0`.

Comment: When you use `this.Invalidate()` does it draw correctly?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Do you have a problem that the `Paint` event isn't triggered when you want, or that when it triggers the drawing is somehow not what you expected?

Comment: The second one, the event triggers but nothing will appear on the screen unless I use `this.Invalidate` in which case the figure is being plotted but it blinks (like if it was being drawn and erased multiple at a slow rate so it becomes noticeable)

Comment: @user20034896 - You need to invalidate, but do it once at the end of the drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a class to handle the model-to-pixel conversions (and in reverse) instead of a function `D2F()`. A class it going to give you a lot more flexibility and it will retain a state of the current scaling values

```
public class Canvas
{
    public Canvas()
    {
        Target = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1);
        Scale = 1;
    }
    public Rectangle Target { get; set; }
    public float Scale { get; set; }

    public void SetModelBounds(float width, float height)
    {
        Scale = Math.Min(Target.Width / width, Target.Height / height);
    }
    public PointF ToPixel(Vector2 point)
    {
        var center = new PointF(Target.Left + Target.Width / 2, Target.Top + Target.Height / 2);
        return new PointF(center.X + Scale * point.X, center.Y - Scale * point.Y);
    }
    public Vector2 FromPixel(Point pixel)
    {
        var center = new PointF(Target.Left + Target.Width / 2, Target.Top + Target.Height / 2);
        return new Vector2((pixel.X - center.X) / Scale, -(pixel.Y - center.Y) / Scale);
    }
}
```

This is setup for each paint event by calling for example

```
Canvas.Target = this.ClientRectangle;
Canvas.SetModelBounds(2f, 2f);
```

The above code is going to place coordinates (-1,-1) on the bottom left of the form surface, and (1,1) on the top right. The pixels per model unit are kept the same for x-axis and y-axis (see `Canvas.Scale`).

Now for the drawing, also use am `Entity` class to hold the drawing geometry, and various other properties such as color, and if the shape is closed or not. Note that if it defines a `Render(Graphics g, Canvas canvas)` method, then it can be called by the form and each entity can handle its own drawing (for the most modular design)

Here is an example:

```
public class Entity 
{
    Entity(bool closed, Color color, params Vector2[] path)
    {
        Color = color;
        Path = new List<Vector2>(path);
        Closed = closed;
    }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public List<Vector2> Path { get; }
    public bool Closed { get; set; }
    public void Render(Graphics g, Canvas canvas)
    {
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color, 1))
        {
            var points = Path.Select(pt => canvas.ToPixel(pt)).ToArray();
            if (Closed)
            {
                g.DrawPolygon(pen, points);
            }
            else
            {
                g.DrawLines(pen, points);
            }
        }
    }
    public static Entity Triangle(Color color, Vector2 center, float width, float height)
    {
        return new Entity(true, color, new Vector2[] {
            new Vector2(center.X-width/2, center.Y - height/3),
            new Vector2(center.X+width/2, center.Y - height/3),
            new Vector2(center.X, center.Y+2*height/3) });
    }
    public static Entity Rectange(Color color, Vector2 center, float width, float height)
    {
        return new Entity(true, color, new Vector2[] {
            new Vector2(center.X-width/2, center.Y-height/2),
            new Vector2(center.X+width/2, center.Y-height/2),
            new Vector2(center.X+width/2, center.Y+height/2),
            new Vector2(center.X-width/2, center.Y+height/2) });
    }
    public static Entity Polygon(Color color, params Vector2[] path)
        => new Entity(true, color, path);
    public static Entity Polyline(Color color, params Vector2[] path)
        => new Entity(false, color, path);
}
```

The above is used in the form as follows

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Canvas Canvas { get; }
    public List<Entity> Entities { get; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Entities = new List<Entity>();
        Canvas = new Canvas();
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        this.Resize += (s, ev) => Invalidate();
        this.Paint += (s, ev) =>
        {
            ev.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            Canvas.Target = ClientRectangle;
            Canvas.SetModelBounds(2f, 2f);
            foreach (var item in Entities)
            {
                item.Render(ev.Graphics, Canvas);
            }
        };
        Entities.Add( .. )
    }
}
```

As you can see the `Paint` event calls the `Render()` method for each entity.

In fact, you can generalize this model using an interface `IRender`. In the example below besides `Entity` that implements the interface, I define a class to draw the coordinate axis called `Axes`.

```
public interface IRender
{
    void Render(Graphics g, Canvas canvas);
}

public class Axes : IRender
{
    public void Render(Graphics g, Canvas canvas)
    {
        PointF origin = canvas.ToPixel(Vector2.Zero);
        PointF xpoint = canvas.ToPixel(Vector2.UnitX);
        PointF ypoint = canvas.ToPixel(Vector2.UnitY);

        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 0))
        {
            pen.CustomEndCap = new AdjustableArrowCap(2f, 5f);
            g.DrawLine(pen, origin, xpoint);
            g.DrawLine(pen, origin, ypoint);
        }
    }
}

public class Entity : IRender
{
...
}
```

and now you can draw with quite a bit of varying things on the screen with the above framework. Here is an example that draws the axis (of unit size) and a few sample entities.

[image: fig1]

```
Entities.Add(Entity.Polygon(Color.Orange, Vector2.Zero, -Vector2.UnitX, -Vector2.One));
Entities.Add(Entity.Rectange(Color.Blue, new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 0.25f, 0.25f));
Entities.Add(Entity.Triangle(Color.Red, new Vector2(0.5f, 0.75f), 0.25f, 0.25f));
Entities.Add(Entity.Polyline(Color.Magenta,
    new Vector2(0f, -0.2f), new Vector2(0f, -0.4f), new Vector2(0.2f, -0.4f),
    new Vector2(0.2f, -0.2f), new Vector2(0.4f, -0.2f), new Vector2(0.4f, -0.4f)));
```

Comment: thank you very much for your example, I still have the same problem but it has helped me to understand a little bit more how to manage the graphical part of the program and to get to a workaround to achieve what I wanted to do.